# WCF client connection problem

Tags: wcf, http-proxy

I am consuming a web service in .NET application with WCF client.

The Endpoint's address of the service is over port 4338, and it is over HTTPS, secured with WS-Security standard.

So the address is something like :

```
https://[servername]:4338/[servicename]/
```

I was not able to communicate to the service with just running the application.
it gave me the following error :

> Could not connect to [servername]:4338
>   TCP error code 10060: A connection
>   attempt failed because the connected
>   party did not properly respond after a
>   period of time, or established
>   connection failed because connected
>   host has failed to respond
>   [servername]:4338

But when I run Fiddler to investigate the http communication, the application start to work, and I will be able to communicate to the service.

As well, I want to add that I have a different service on the same web server that hosts the first service, and that second service's address is hosted on port 8080, and I am able to communicate with it with WCF client (without running Fiddler).

So, I googled and I found that it might be related to the proxy settings. Do you know what the problem is, and how can I solve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have proxy set in Internet Explorer, it may cause the problem. What happens when you open https://[servername]:4338/[servicename]/ in Internet Explorer?

Answer (score 1):

Fiddler acts as an Internet proxy server. In general, any symptom of the form: "it works when I use Fiddler" means "it works when there's a (different) proxy server".

Check your proxy server settings. In particular, as empi suggested, try it in a browser. If it works there, it could be due to the fact that the browser has the proxy settings configured, and that you do not have them configured for WCF.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks empi for the reply.
I found the answer.
Actually in our company we have a proxy settings through "Automatic configuration script"
and depends on the web sites we are targeting internally, the script will point us to the proper proxy.
So, from the script I got the proper proxy address.
and in my .NET application I added this code
WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = new WebProxy("http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080");
and that fixed the problem
So WCF client was not detecting the setting of the automatic script.
and this is the reason it worked when I run Fiddler, because Fiddler listen to the http communication, and send it again through the settings.